What is the proper way to boot Debian 12 Install CB from GRUB? Can't detect install Media
I need to set up Debian 12 on a remote system and can only access the install media through GRUB.  I can boot the image, but it can't find the install media.  My /etc/grub.d/40_custom entry is as follows:
menuentry 'Debian Install Image' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    set isofile='/images/debian-12.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso'
    set initrdfile='/images/debian-12.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.gz'
    loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
    linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz findiso=$isofile iso-scan/filename=$isofile priority=low noeject
    initrd $initrdfile
}

The initrd was copied from the ISO's /install.amd/initrd.gz
The same method was used almost verbatim on a Debian 10 system and works great. Any advice for helping it to find the install media?
EDITS: I want to clarify, it's the Debian install media I want to try and use, not a live CD.  It appears that the Debian 12 installer media initrds don't actually have the filesystem (ext2, etc) modules needed to be able to read an iso install media from a hard drive any more. I was incredulous at first, but it seems this is actually the case.  This leaves me without being able to use installer media with the packages already included.

I am using Kubuntu so I downloaded Debian live kde.
I have a data partition (hd1,5) with an /ISO folder, so that is my path.
Parts of entry from older gparted ISO boot and from grub inside ISO. This entry is actually in my livecdimage.cfg in my /ISO folder.
    menuentry "Debian Live system (amd64)" --hotkey=l {
        insmod part_gpt
        set isofile="/ISO/debian-live-12.5.0-amd64-kde.iso"
        loopback loop (hd1,5)$isofile
        linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz-6.1.0-18-amd64 boot=live config union=overlay username=user noswap noprompt ip=frommedia findiso=$isofile toram=filesystem.squashfs
        initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
    }

Just rebooted and booted the live ISO with above boot stanza.
I have many ISO in my /ISO folder. I prefer to create one entry in grub's 40_custom as a configfile to a grub/text file (livecdimage.cfg) in my /ISO folder. Example of boot stanza added to 40_custom.
    menuentry 'Live ISOs in nvme_data drive' {
    search --set=root --label nvme_data
    configfile /ISO/livecdimage.cfg
    }
    # spacer line
    menuentry " " {
    set root=
    }
    
    menuentry "System restart" {
    echo "System rebooting..."
    insmod reboot
    reboot
    }
    
    menuentry "System shutdown" {
          echo "System shutting down..."
          insmod halt
          halt
    }

The livecdimage.cfg is just a text file with grub boot stanza. That way I do not have to remember to update grub with changes to 40_custom as I just edit livecdimage.cfg with new ISO boot stanzas.

Thank-you very much for the answer.  I have been able to get live media to work.  It's the install media I'm trying to get to function.

The live media for KDE has the calamares installer in System settings. Almost all my installs are and have been Ubuntu & I have not like the older Ubuntu installer, but now like clamares. LIve media lets me test & run commands rather than just jumping straight into install.
